# Ocaml - Check if every digit of a given int is less than "base" recursively

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Check if every digit of a given int is less than "base" in a recursive manner.

In "pseudo-code"

```
 boolean is_base ( int base, int num)
{
    if num = 0
        return true;
    else if num mod 10 < base 
        is_base (base, num/10)
    else return false
}
```

Ocaml code

```
let rec is_base base num= 
    if num = 0 then 1
    else if num mod 10 < base then is_base base num/10
    else 0
```

Is a looping recursion.

Comment: Printing arguments at the beginning of the function should give you some information about what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function application operator (that's in OCaml is just a juxtaposition of a function and its arguments, e.g., `f x`) has higher precedence than arithmetic operators (i.e., it binds tighter), so the `f x/10` expression is treated by OCaml as `(f x) / 10`.

In your case `is_base base num/10` is parsed as `(is_base base num)/10`, i.e., first a recursive call is made with `base` and `num` parameters, then the result is divided by `10`. Since your recursive call is always made with the same parameter, it never terminates.

Also, if you would use `bool` for representing booleans (i.e., `true` and `false`) compiler will tell you that your code is incorrect. Always use the most concrete type, this will help the compiler to provide better diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

(Your code is a bit of a moving target....)

There's no need to change `num` in the code you show. You can pass `num / 10` without changing `num`.

In general this is how to write functional code. What you would normally consider to be a mutable value becomes a function parameter instead.

Comment: Yes, Ive rewritten my question